# Secondary sorting in Magento

Tags: sql, magento, sorting

I have come across a problem which my developer says there is no solution to.

I have an ecommerce site www.lovefashion.pk roughly 800 products to date. It has categories with collections of products from a particular brand and New Arrivals and Sale pages that show  a number of categories. The issue I am faced with is the way Magento displays these products on catalog pages.

We create a custom sort 'BY date' and called it 'Latest' so I would choose a date for a collection and the catalog pages would show the collection with newest sort by date first and so on. Issue is with secondary sorting now. I have products with design codes say Brand A code 1-A, Brand A code 1-B, Brand A code 2-A and so on. When creating these products, we go alphabetically like 1-A,1-B, 2-A etc.

Say a collection has 15 products and i have given all its products a sort by date of 15th April. Magento does the date sorting OK but secondary sorting i.e by product ID (oldest to newest) is what we cant find a way to implement. It shows products now with latest ID first, i.e 20-B, 20-A, 19-B, and so on till 1-A e.g http://www.lovefashion.pk/shop-by-price/

Is there a way to solve this problem? or can SQL manipulation do the trick? Will aprreicate any help

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question. Can you tell us a little more about what you are trying to do? I think you want the products on each page reversed, but the pages to keep the order they have, yes? or do you want the page to go 'Asim Jofa Luxury Lawn Collection 2014 / 1-A' then 'Orient Lawn Kurti Collection 2014 / 01-B' then 'Orient Lawn Kurti Collection 2014 / 01-A' and so on?

Anyway, I think all you need to do is code a secondary sorting of the collection for each page which could be coded in the `list.phtml` file.

Psuedo code:

```
get the collection sorted by date and paginated
reverse the collection
pass the collection into the existing foreach(){echo(<li>product info</li>)}
```

So 'reverse the collection' might be tricky. And strictly you want to sort by sku on 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B - but I'm sure your developer can figure it out.

```
$reversed_collection = array_reverse($current_page_collection->toArray());
```

*might* work but I think the toArray will loose all the class types so it's not the same as reversing the object.

Collections are like arrays so `end($current_page_collection)` and `prev($current_page_collection)` might work but you would have to try it (and report back if it works). In that case a simple for loop to iterate over each item of the colection.

If you are making a custom filter then really it is just a case of putting each item of the collection into an array with an appropriate key and sorting with `ksort()`.

So it is my opinion that it can be sorted that way, but it should be done in two stages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ll get back to my developer with this and report what he has to say